# Add cert file in retrofit request

Tags: android, https, request, retrofit2, tls1.2

I'm trying to integrate a banking API in my mobile app (Android) and, being in sandbox mode, I have a public key (the certificate) and private key that should be on each request. In doc, this is how the request looks like:

```
curl -i -k --cert public.cert --cert-type PEM --key private.key --key-type PEM "endpoint.com" -H "Correlation-ID: OK1200" -H "WEB-API-Key: MY_API_KEY" -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN"
```

So, being in sandbox mode, how should I add both private key and public key to my retrofit requests?

Comment: Did you test putting the cert file in `raw` directory and loading it where your `OkHttpClient.Builder` is?

`InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.public);`

You can start by this approach, and then provide details on your progress so that people can actually help on this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is TLS(transport layer security) implementation. It is a usual procedure in terms of secure apps.
If you are using `OkHttp` as your network client for `Retrofit` you will be able to do it relatively easily since `OkHttp` supports it out of the box.
There are several options, one of which to do everything manually, but I would not recommend that.
Instead, I would recommend [`okhttp-tls`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls) library which was done exactly for that.
There may be some specifics, but generally, your code should look something like this:

```
// keyPair is a KeyPair(PublicKey, PrivateKey) where PublicKey and PrivateKey may be implemented via AndroidKeyStore
//certificate is X509Certificate which can bo obtained (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(assets.open("pathToCertificate.pem"))
HeldCertificate rootCertificate = HeldCertificate(keyPair, certificate);
HandshakeCertificates clientCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addTrustedCertificate(rootCertificate.certificate())
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager())
    .build();
```

Comment: Is there any relation between keypair and certificate ? With what properties we should generate Keypair in Android Keystore ? Is .pem file supported in Android ? if yes, can we read it as inputStream ? if no, can we use .cer , .der or .pfx ?